# Localizing SharePoint 2013 report viewer web part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, localization, report-viewer

How can I change what is written on the Report viewer web part when it is waiting for the parameters to be set like :

[image]

Also, how to change the text of the apply button in the parameters area:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "configure" those. I'd just add Script Editor web part to the page containing JavaScript that replaces the strings when page is loaded.